# Mouse pointer jumps with external HDD

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mouse

I have a new (3 weeks old) WD My passport HDD 1 TB, and I use Windows 7. I run the HDD through a USB 2.0 port, since my computer doesn't have USB 3.0 ports. My mouse is connected via a USB port as well. It happens occasionally that when I try to access folders on the HDD, the mouse pointer lags and jumps in the direction I moved it to, specially if the folder have many files and folders, and when these folders change there shape according to there contents, also it sometimes happen when I check the size of a large folder.

When it happens it does when I move the pointer over an open window of this drive.
I doubted the antivirus software I have (AVG) so I disabled it but still happens, maybe reduced not really sure but it happens.

Taking in consideration that the drive have shown no sign of other issues. All the WD utility tests, and data life guard tests I ran came out "Passed". The smart report is OK. But when this condition happened I began to suspect the drive. Do I have a bad drive here??

Comment: run ProcessExplroer in background. Do you get DPC or Interrupt storm at the time you get the mouse pointer issues?

Comment: I'm sorry but what is DPC or interrupt storm?? and how do I detect them??

Comment: Do you see such a high Interrupts usage? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/ProcessExplorer_DPC_1.png

Comment: There are some jumps on the graph, but instantaneous. How do I show the box that you showed which says: CPU 83.38   49.78% interrupts  23:83:32 I looked and I can't find it.

Comment: when I enlarge the graph and point below the red area under the graph at these jumps, it gives: explorer, AVG, or firefox (My browser) stuff like that..

Comment: Most of the jumps in this graph are caused by the antivirus (which I enabled to provoke the lag as much as possible, since I can't control when it happens). Here's the graph: http://postimage.org/image/9315tk4b9/

Comment: Please tell me what to do to locate the problem.. And what CPU percentage I should worry about for these interruptions ??

Comment: uninstall AVG completely and test again.

Comment: I don't know if the existence of interruptions is a normal thing even if it was small. I hope you can tell me what's the safe usage %. I've done some tests with AVG and without it. AVG doesn't affect the interruptions though it increases the lag. Do these interruptions something I should worry about?? When the lagging happens the interruptions doesn't get affected... Here are the results of my tests: postimage.org/image/3x8o4fl3f/

Comment: the dllhost.exe causes some high CPU usgae. Looks like Windows tries to generate thumbnails of the file on the HDD. And yes, ISR/DPCs are normal for transferring data.

Comment: from the screenshot it looks like Windows hangs while generating the thumbnails for pictures and videos. Disable this in the explorer options.

Comment: So what is causing the lag (specifically on this drive)??

Comment: try it out. Disable the thumbnail creation and look if this fixes it.

Comment: It happens also when I try to check the size of some big files, it's not only about thumbnails..

Answer (score 0):

ok, I add this here as answer, because I need some space (convert it to a comment if needed).

I need to know what happens on your system, so I want to run a xperf trace. [Install the Windows Performance Toolkit](http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=146919), copy the following text into a .cmd file:

```
@echo off

xperf -on Latency+PROC_THREAD+LOADER+CSWITCH+FILENAME+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+DISK_IO+DRIVERS -f kernel.etl -stackwalk Profile+CSwitch+DiskReadInit+DiskWriteInit+DiskFlushInit+FileCreate+FileCleanup+FileClose+FileRead+FileWrite -BufferSize 1024 -MaxBuffers 1024 -MaxFile 1024 -FileMode Circular

echo Reproduce the problem now, hit any key to finish, collect Merged Etl file

pause

echo merging etl... 

xperf -d xperfSlowIOHighCPUcir.etl

@echo on
```

Now open a cmd prompt with admin rights ad run the command. Now minimize the cmd Window and when you have the issue again, switch to to the CMD, wait 30s and press a key to stop logging. Compress the xperfSlowIOHighCPUcir.etl as 7z and upload it (SkDrive, Dropbox) and post a link to it.

With this file I can see what your system does when you have the issue.

Comment: Can you provide some tips in your answer about what future readers should do with the .etl file, or perhaps link to some tutorials? Not everyone might want to send files to you (no offence!), and you may not even be around to respond. They should know what they can do on their own to diagnose the issue, or at least how to get started on it.

Comment: I provided some basic guides on msfn.org, but in his case I can't really see what the issue is. OS I can't say, look at this or this.